# Firefox: which tab is taking CPU

Tags: macos, firefox, tabs, cpu-usage

How to see exactly which tab is taking up CPU?

I know how to do this in Chrome and Safari but here it's not obvious...

Firefox version: `36` on OSX

Answer (score 3):

couple of years later, just in case someone is still searching, modern versions of Firefox provide:

1. `about:performance` for cpu consumption of every tab and add-on
2. `about:memory` same for memory consumption
3. the [gecko profiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) that can be opened from the menu *Tools > Web Developer > Performance*